# detect if "std::function" points to "std::shared_ptr" object?

Tags: c++11, stl

is it possible to rebuild the connection back from a `std::function` pointer back to an `std::shared_ptr<>` object instance? I wanna know to which object holds this `std::function<>` it's function ptr.

For example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void doIt1( int i );
    void doIt2( int i );
};

void f() {
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr( new Foo );

    std::function<void(int)> fp = get_funcptr_from_somewhere();

    if( fp.target<void(int)>() == ptr ) {
        // I've found it!!
    }

}
```

The problem is `fp.target` is only a function ptr and I could build a function pointer again out of `ptr` but this I don't know which function of that object it is pointless (interestingly target reports `nullptr` if the object was deleted). Which does help, but is there any other possibility to correlate an std::function<> object to an existing std::shared_ptr instance?

Thank you very much!

Comment: No it's not possible. `std::function` is a black box, with a specific interface. All you know is that you can use it as a function but can't really know what it will actually call if all you have is the `std::function` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `ptr` is not invokable, so it **cannot** be the target of `std::function<void(int)>`.  The only objects that can be the target of `std::function<void(int)>` are those that can be invoked with `(int)`.

This is generally true of every `std::shared_ptr` -- there are no invokable `std::shared_ptr`s, so they are never the `target` of a `std::function`.

An object is invokable if you can go `object( blah )` for some `blah`.

`target<X>()` only returns non-`nullptr` if the invokable object stored is exactly of type `X`.  If you have stored a `bind` or `mem_fun` expression, this means there is no way practical to get it back out.

You can arrange so that your `std::function`s are constructed in very particular ways using very particular types, and on that subset of `std::function`s use `target<X>()` to extract out the backing objects, but this is not generally a useful technique, and is instead intended for narrow special cases.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard defines for function objects in `[function.objects]` (12.8) only their names and the effect they have. It does not specify a concrete implementation.

So if you have an `std::function` function object there is no way of knowing what function with what arguments it will call.